# How to feed awk input from both pipe and file?

Tags: linux, awk

I was wondering how do I get awk to take a string from the pipe output and a file?

I've basically have a chain of commands that eventually will spit out a string. I want to check this string against a csv file (columns separated by commas). Then, I want to find the first row in the file that contains the string in the 7th column of the csv file and print out the contents of the 5th column of that line. Also, I don't know linux command line utilities/awk too well, so feel free to suggest completely different methods. :)

CSV file contents look like this:

```
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,etc...
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,etc...
etc...
```

My general line of thought:

```
(rest of commands that will give a string) | awk -F ',' 'if($5 == string){print $7;exit}' filename.txt
```

Can this be done? If so, how do I tell awk to compare against that string?
I've found some stuff about using a `-` symbol with `ARGV[]` before the filename, but couldn't get it working.

Comment: *Don't* use a pipe. Store the searched string in a variable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As Karoly suggests,

```
str=$( rest of commands that will give a string )
awk -v s="$str" -F, '$7==s {print $5; exit}' file
```

If you want to feed awk with a pipe:

```
cmds | awk -F, 'NR==FNR {str=$0; next}; $7==str {print $5}' - file
```

I think the first option is more readable.

Comment: I welcomed your second answer as you sometimes want to do `cmd | awk '...' file -`

Answer (score 0):

Skip the temp shell variable altogether :

```
echo 'BEGIN { OFS = RS } /2023/ { print $2, $3, $4, $5 }' |
```

> 

```
gawk -f- -b -p- <( gdate )
```

---

```
Dec
26
17:03:17
EST
```

---

```
    # gawk profile, created Tue Dec 26 17:03:17 2023

    # BEGIN rule(s)

    BEGIN {
     1      OFS = RS
    }

    # Rule(s)

     1  /2023/ { # 1
     1      print $2, $3, $4, $5
    }
```

Or if you prefer just a copy of the parsed syntax plus the execution without the profiler :

```
echo '{ print NR,FNR,NF,ARGV[0], FILENAME, $2, $3, $4, $5 } END { OFS = "\f"
       __ = "argv"; for (_ in PROCINFO[__]) print "\t"_, PROCINFO[__][_] }' |
```

---

```
gtee >( gawk -o- -f- >&2; ) | 
 
gawk -nMb -f- <( gdate )
```

---

```
{
    print NR, FNR, NF, ARGV[0], FILENAME, $2, $3, $4, $5
}

END {
    OFS = "\f"
    __ = "argv"
    for (_ in PROCINFO[__]) {
        print "\t" _, PROCINFO[__][_]
    }
}
```

---

```
1 1 6 gawk /dev/fd/13 Dec 26 17:14:19 EST
    0
         gawk
    1
         -nMb
    2
         -f-
    3
         /dev/fd/13
```